# Syntax highlight do R ainda não está funcionando automaticamente

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, syntax-highlighting

Achei que o syntax highlight do R estava funcionando automaticamente... ledo engano, na verdade foi a tag do SQL.

Alguma previsão para implementar isso no R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mudei a configuração da tag de `none` para `default`. Deve melhorar um pouco, mas o highlight de R mesmo [depende de habilitarem mais opções para os moderadores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234056/can-we-have-more-tag-based-syntax-highlighting-options).

Comment: Valeu, muito melhor do que nada!

Answer (score 1):

[Nosso pedido foi atendido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249799/167534), e agora os moderadores podem associar as tags a mais algumas linguagens, incluindo R. Não sei dizer quanto a configuração `lang-default` funcionava para R, mas supostamente `lang-r` deve funcionar melhor.